# Typescript compiler errors from directory I have excluded

Tags: typescript

Why am I getting Typescript compiler errors like:

> ../node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts(50,17): error TS1005: ',' expected.

when this is my tsconfig.json, where I am specifically excluding that path:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Declaration files are still compiled. You can fix the error by setting `"skipLibCheck": true` in _compilerOptions_

Comment: *not fix, but skip. Also probably in this file used some typescript features from version higher than you have